# Node js web app restart issue

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

js site which i deployed on Azure.

Site was working fine but i made some changes but changes not appearing on the site. How to restart or clear site cache on Azure portal.

One more thing that post methods are not working in this site as well how to enable post method in Azure ?

I already tried to restart my web app from Azure portal but not success.

Posted my issue https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/090831ae-41ff-4091-a7ec-466041904c10/nodejs-app-restart-cache-issue?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview here as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could restart your app by following steps below on Azure portal.

1. In the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), open the blade for the web app.
2. Click **Overview**.
3. Click **Restart** button to restart your app.

[image]

Secondly, you could check the code whether it has been changed on Azure with Kudu which could be accessed via `https://<yourwebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.
Then cd to `site/wwwroot` folder, you will now be able to see your application files.

By default, Azure doesn't restrict any HTTP request method. Maybe you have made a mistake in configuring `web.config` file, which can be found on [this article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps). You can check this [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started) if needed.